# NOTEPAD++ Line break for every group of 3 decimal numbers

Tags: notepad++, line, break

This is probably very silly for you. But I'm no programmer. So please bear with this.

In Notepad++ how do I add a line break after 3 decimal numbers automatically?

For example I have a long line like:

```
-2.851608 109.752381 12.935308 -2.851387 98.083699 12.451827 -5.771117 97.505013 12.420679
```

Which I'd like to transform into:

```
-2.851608 109.752381 12.935308
-2.851387 98.083699 12.451827
-5.771117 97.505013 12.420679
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The 2 sets of numbers are identical. please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:[\d.-]+\h+){3}\K`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         : start non capture group
  [\d.-]+   : 1 or more digit or dot or minus
  \h+       : 1 or more horizontal space
){3}        : group must appear 3 times
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
-2.851608 109.752381 12.935308 
-2.851387 98.083699 12.451827 
-5.771117 97.505013 12.420679
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

Find what : `((\d+\.\d+\s){3})`
Replace with: `$1\n`

with Wrap around and Regular expression checked and Replace All.